# Cannot convert a symbolic input/output to a numpy array

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to run a deep learning code that I found in a tutorial in order to familiarise myself with resnet50, keras and tensorflow with python 3.7. When I run my code, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a symbolic value to a NumPy call, which is not supported. Or, you may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model.

I tried to use the following fix as mentioned on stack overflow:

`from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution`

`disable_eager_execution()`

Without any success. My full code can be seen below:

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution
import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

# Download the architecture of ResNet50 with ImageNet weights
base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

# Taking the output of the last convolution block in ResNet50
x = base_model.output

# Adding a Global Average Pooling layer
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

# Adding a fully connected layer having 1024 neurons
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)

# Adding a fully connected layer having 2 neurons which will
# give probability of image having either dog or cat
predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

# Model to be trained
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

# Training only top layers i.e. the layers which we have added in the end
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# Compiling the model
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'],
              experimental_run_tf_function=False)

# Creating objects for image augmentations
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

# Proving the path of training and test dataset
# Setting the image input size as (224, 224)
# We are using class mode as binary because there are only two classes in our data
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('training_set',
                                                 target_size = (224, 224),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('test_set',
                                            target_size = (224, 224),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

# Training the model for 5 epochs
model.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                         epochs = 5,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 2000)

# We will try to train the last stage of ResNet50
for layer in base_model.layers[0:143]:
  layer.trainable = False

for layer in base_model.layers[143:]:
  layer.trainable = True

# Training the model for 10 epochs
model.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                         epochs = 10,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 2000)

# Saving the weights in the current directory
model.save_weights("resnet50_weights.h5")

# Predicting the final result of image

test_image = image.load_img('cat_or_dog_test.jpg', target_size = (224, 224))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)\

# Expanding the 3-d image to 4-d image.
# The dimensions will be Batch, Height, Width, Channel
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)

# Predicting the final class
classifier = LogisticRegression()
result = classifier.predict(test_image)

# Fetching the class labels
labels = training_set.class_indices
labels = list(labels.items())

# Printing the final label
for label, i in labels:
    if i == result:
        print("The test image has: ", label)
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when using: from keras import Input;
But, when I change to: from tensorflow.keras import Input, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the following line is where the error occurs:

```py
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
```

The reason is probably that you try to apply a numpy function to a tensor. Don't do that. Either convert your tensor to numpy or use a function that work on tensors. Normally, I'd say prefer the second option over the first one (it will prevent unnecessary conversions and make your code more efficient). In your case you will need to convert your tensor to numpy because you are using sklearn afterward:

```py
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image.numpy(), axis=0)
```

Comment: i haven't reproduce the error, however based on your suggestion i may add : instead of using test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0) he can use test_image = tf.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0) as this is tesnorflow function.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to DL and I received a similar error a nd the following has helped me.

Try:

```
del base_model
```

Before:

```
base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
```

and also simultaneously:

Try:

```
del model
```

Before:

```
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
```

Please let me know if this has helped you or hasn't :) .

Answer (score 0):

Try using tensorflow.keras.something instead of keras.something.

It worked for me.

Ofcourse you have to also import tensorlfow